# Use Eclipse 4 product definition for integration tests

Tags: junit, integration-testing, eclipse-rcp, e4

I developed two eclipse plug-ins: a server and a client.
Either can be run separately in their own application, or they run in the same application as "embedded" mode.

For each operation mode, I created an eclipse product. The embedded product is basically the same as the client, but it also contains the server plugin which is then automatically activated.

Now, when it comes to setting up integration tests, I run into a problem: the product for the client and the embedded application use the same application id. Is there any way to distinguish between the two? Basically, I want to integration-test exactly what I defined in my `embedded.product` (of course with additional junit testing plugins). Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Are you sure the dependency graph of the client is not pulling anything from the server? What happens is that both launch configs end up launching the whole "embedded" product. Is that right?

Comment: @AdamHorvath: Yes, the client has no dependency at all on the server. It only searches through all OSGI bundles, and if it finds the server, it activates that bundle. So to test the embedded version I can cheat this a little by specifying a dependency on the server from my test plug-in. But I find this kind of ugly ;). Another point: other plug-ins that are specified in the feature and are not mentioned anywhere as an actual dependency are also left out in tests.